# Rails dependent: :destroy on acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Ihave a Rails 5 app and I would like to destroy tags when the parent record is destroyed. I am trying to do something like:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_taggable_on :jobs, dependent: :destroy
    ...
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:dependent=>:destroy}:Hash Did you mean? to_s to_set
```

The [documentation for acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) does not explicitly say you can use dependent: :destroy, but [this issue](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/662) makes me think you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that doing `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.destroy_all` removes all tags for me.